# Why were there few people answering my questions?

Tags: discussion

When I first joined math SE, typically within the 1st hour of asking, I can get an answer for my question. These few days it took quite a while for my questions to be answer, if they were even answered. Is this site getting less popular or something?

Comment: Maybe it became more popular with more people answering questions and more questions being asked but rate of growth of questions surpass the rate of growth of answers.

Comment: This might be related (to some extent): [Is the interest in this community falling?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8514/is-the-interest-in-this-community-falling)

Comment: $39$ days is a pretty short baseline; I’m not sure that you can really judge any trend on that basis. However, it is likely that the number of unanswered questions and the time lag between question and answer will increase as the number of questions per day increases. A few months ago I could still see at least the front-page listing of every question; this is no longer true, though I still see a very high percentage.

Comment: @LateLearner Another reason might be that noone interested in the particular field is online or willing to answer (for example, I don't like to answer questions which give orders or look like copied homework assignments without being tagged as such and without "comment" on the OP's side).
I must say the more interesting and the less specialized a question is, the likelier you are to be noticed. Also, kindness helps - as always.